# Python 2.7 optparse not reading 2nd flag

Tags: python, optparse

Can someone help me out here? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to get my second option to be read from the command line.

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser=OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-s", action="store", type="string", dest="scenario")
parser.add_option("-l", action="store", type="string", dest="logger")
(options, args)=parser.parse_args()

print options.scenario
print options.logger
print options
```

Print Results

```
>>python test.py -sfoo -lbar
foo
None
{'logger': None, 'scenario': 'foo'}
```

Additionally, I cannot put a space in between the flag and argument `-sfoo` is ok but `-s foo` is not. It's pretty annoying. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: optparse is depreciated in favor of argparse: https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user3757614 suggests in his comment, use `argparse` instead.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-s', '--scenario', required=True, dest="scenario")
parser.add_argument('-l', '--logger', required=True, dest="logger")

args = parser.parse_args()

print args
print args.scenario
print args.logger
```

And in the command line:

```
$ python test.py -s test1 -l test2
Namespace(logger='test2', scenario='test1')
test1
test2
```